# If a Quadratic $ax^2+bx+c\geq 0,$ then why can't we say Discriminant $D(b^2-4ac)=0$ only and $a>0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics

If a Quadratic $ax^2+bx+c\geq 0,$ then why can't we say Discriminant $D(b^2-4ac)=0$ only and $a>0$?

**My Doubt:**

When Discriminant $(D=b^2-4ac)=0$ then we obtain quadratic $ax^2+bx+c=0$ as $a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2$.

Since $a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2\geq0\; \forall x\in \mathbb R$ if $a>0$.

But when we solve quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c\geq0$ we do $D\leq 0.$ Why can't we do only $D=0$

Reference [Show that if $a > 0$, then $ax^2 + bx + c ≥ 0$ for all values of $x$ if and only if $b^2 − 4ac ≤ 0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885716/show-that-if-a-0-then-ax2-bx-c-%e2%89%a5-0-for-all-values-of-x-if-and-only)

Comment: The shows you that $D\ge 0$ if $a \ge 0$.  But it doesn't say that $D$ is *exactly* $0$ if $a \ge 0$ which would be, of course, absurd.  $D \ne 0$ if and only if  $b^2 \ne 4ac$ and there no reason to expect $b^2 = 4ac$.

Comment: The answer really is simple.  If $a \ne 0$ then the solutions to $ax^2 + bx +c =$ can only be and will always be (if possible) $x =\frac {-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$.  Such solutions *exist* if and only if $D \ge 0$.  So if $D \ge 0$ then $f(x)=0$ somewhere.  If $D < 0$ then $f(x)$ *never* equals $0$ and is *always* entirely less than $0$ or entirely greater than $0$.   Whether $D$ does or does not equal $0$ or whether $D >0$ or whether $D < 0$ has *nothing* to do with $a$.  $D<0$ or $D>0$ or $D=0$ has only to do with whether $f(x)=0$ has no sol. $f(x)$ has two sol. or if $f(x)$ has one sol.

Comment: Suppose that $D\gt 0$. Then, $ax^2+bx+c=a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2-\frac{D}{4a}$ is negative for $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$, which contradicts $ax^2+bx+c\geqslant 0$. Therefore, we have $D\leqslant 0$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $Ax^2+Bx+C&gt;0 $ for all real $x$ if and only if $A&gt;0$ and $B^2-4AC&lt;0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2950991/show-that-ax2bxc0-for-all-real-x-if-and-only-if-a0-and-b2-4ac0)